# GIT stashing and switching between branches issue - work from one branch appeared on the other without merging

Tags: git, git-stash

I was working recently with multiple branches at once (3 branches to be exact, let's call them A, B and C).

I was on branch A and then decided to switch to B, but I had some work, not ready for commit. So I stashed it and switched.

After I reveiwed code on B, I switched to C, to make some immediate corrections. Again, I needed to switch to B, so I stashed them.

Then I decided to switch to A branch, in order to start working from last "checkpoint" I applied last stash.

Then strange things started to happen - I was seeing partial changes from branch C.

I know it is messy workflow, but today it happened to me...

Since I didn't merge anything, how is it possible to happen?

...the worst part is I deleted all stashed except one I appied, thinking it is some old, unnecessary stash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about stashes...

They are shared between branches. If you stash work on one branch it can be easily applied (so, it is visible from other branch) on another branch.

I must have applied stash from branch C to branch A. That's why I was seeing partial work from A - because I applied only a stash, not whole branch.

**HOW TO RECOVER LOST STASH**

When stashing, the special kind of commit is

After deleteing it, it still can be found in GIT history, as @Code-Apprentice mentiond and can be inspected with `git reflog`, which is just shhortcut for

```
git log --reflog --oneline
```

In my case lost commit appeared as:

```
b10b2fc (refs/stash) WIP on branch: 78beda0 [COMMIT MESSAGE]
```

So I can merge this commit into my branch (it means to me a couple of conflicts, but it is better than just redoing everything):

```
git merge b10b2fc
```

Answer (score 1):

> Then I decided to switch to A branch, in order to start working from last "checkpoint" I applied last stash.

The "last stash" that you applied here is the stash that you made while on branch C. This is why you see the changs you made on branch C earlier. To do this correctly, you need to apply the second stash from the top:

```
git checkout A
git stash apply stash@{1}
```

> I know it is messy workflow, but today it happened to me...

This seems like a reasonable workflow. As a programmer, we are often pulled in multiple directions due to manager requirements. The whole point of `git stash` is to let us deal with these kinds of interuptions. You just need to use it correctly.

> ...the worst part is I deleted all stashed except one I appied, thinking it is some old, unnecessary stash.

This is a problem. Most likely this means that you lost your work from the two stashes on branches A and C. As a last resort, you might be able to restore some of your work by inspecting the output `git reflog`.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I posted it rather about "how thiis could happen". And to warn everybdy who might be vulnerable to that... I removed my work :P

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Added some more detail. I think the main difference between my answer and your self-answer is that I show the correct command to use in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

### Stash called harmful

A stash is a very weird and complicated beast, and it is all too easy (as you've discovered) to misuse it.

Of necessity, a stash is intimately tied to the HEAD (current branch), the index (describing a new possible commit on the current branch), and the working tree at the instant the stash is created:

```
index-commit ⬅︎ working-tree-commit
         |         |
          \       /    
          ⬇︎      ⬇︎
         HEAD-commit
```

The arrows in that diagram point in the direction of parentage. Thus, the working-tree-commit is a kind of merge (a very weird kind of merge, a merge and then some).

You can actually *see* that complication of commits by calling `git log` on your stash:

```
$ git log stash --graph --oneline
*   778388c (refs/stash) WIP on master: 3429244 z
|\  
| * dcd25d1 index on master: 3429244 z
|/  
* 3429244 (HEAD -> master, branch) z
```

The HEAD commit is not "inside" the stash, but the other two commits in that diagram are. And remember, the index is a snapshot of *all* the files in the HEAD snapshot, which is *all* your files at the time the commit was made; and the working tree snapshot is a snapshot of *all* the files you can see.

Thus, if you apply this stash to a different branch, you're going to pour into both the index and the working tree a whole bunch of stuff that was true of this branch. And you can readily do that, because, as you rightly say, you can have multiple stashes and they are all globally visible.

Thus I don't recommend using stashes very much. In the particular situation you describe, I would describe this reaction as wrong:

> but I had some work, not ready for commit. So I stashed it

No. That is a mark of an inflexible attitude towards what a commit is. You are *always* "ready for commit". You should commit *early and often*. There is nothing at all wrong with a WIP (work-in-progress) commit. After all, you can always squash your WIP commits out of existence later, when you revise your history to summarize it in a nice series of meaningful commits.

So, in both cases where you stashed, I would have just made a WIP commit. This is much safer because it is directly tied to the branch — in fact, it *is* the branch. Just give it a `"WIP"` message so you'll know instantly when you check it out again that you were in the middle of something.

<sub>(So when *do* you need a stash? You need it in that rare situation where you can't even do what I just said. The index is partially formed, possibly containing some stuff that it shouldn't, and so you are in the middle of some elaborate rebalancing act between what the index says and what the working tree says, and there just isn't time to work it all out and form a true commit. That is why the stash preserves the state of *both* the index *and* the working tree: it's because they are *both* in a sort of partial half-baked state, and you are *so* busy and *so* confused that you just need to preserve *that half-baked state* and get the heck out of here.)</sub>